# Karate UI : data driven testing not working properly when used driver.quit()

Tags: karate

We are exploring Karate UI(already using Karate for API testing). For exploring purpose we are using https://www.delta.com/ and its working fine. However have observed following behavior while implementing data driven test

Following is the simple feature file for search destination

```
Feature: Karate UI POC

Background: To set the browser driver

  * configure driver = { type: 'chromedriver', executable: "path to exe"}
  * def data= 
    """
    { 
    fromDes: '#(from)'
    }
    """
  Scenario: Launch the application search for the valid flights

  Given driver 'https://www.delta.com/'
  * driver.maximize()
  * waitUntil("document.readyState == 'complete'")
  * waitForEnabled('#fromAirportName').click()
  * waitForEnabled('#search_input')
  * clear('#search_input')
  * input('#search_input',data.fromDes)
  * driver.quit()
```

From data.feature file I am making a call to above feature file as follows

```
* table destinations
  | from            |
  | 'NEW YORK'      | 
  | 'BOSTON'        | 

* call read('delta.feature') destinations
```

On executing the test I am getting following error

```
17:26:55.443 [main] ERROR com.intuit.karate - org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connect to localhost:9515 [localhost/127.0.0.1, localhost/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1] failed: Connection refused: connect, http call failed after 2054 milliseconds for URL: http://localhost:9515/session/6fa82b59df1c1c845974c2f52d481d11/url
17:26:55.445 [main] ERROR com.intuit.karate - http request failed: 
org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connect to localhost:9515 [localhost/127.0.0.1, localhost/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1] failed: Connection refused: connect
17:26:55.445 [main] WARN  c.i.k.d.chromedriver_1592481370453 - session delete failed: 
org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connect to localhost:9515 [localhost/127.0.0.1, localhost/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1] failed: Connection refused: connect
17:26:55.445 [main] DEBUG com.intuit.karate.shell.Command - closing command: chromedriver_1592481370453
```

1) However if I remove statement **driver.quit()** test is working fine.

2) Is it a right approach for data driven testing in Karat UI, as we are using it quit well in Karate API

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to use `quit()` at all, Karate will do it automatically.

Can you also try with version 0.9.6.RC3

If you still see an issue, follow this process and we will make sure it is fixed: https://github.com/intuit/karate/tree/develop/examples/ui-test

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply ! I have checked with 0.9.6RC3, however it is showing same error if I execute with **driver.quit()**. So I'll raise issue as per your suggestion for this.

Comment: @ShekharPatil not sure if you understood what I said. don't use quit(). assume that such a keyword does not exist. and just a reminder, raising an issue is not enough - read those instructions clearly

Comment: sorry for misunderstanding here, yeah it is working fine for me without a quit() with version 0.9.5 and 0.9.6RC3. I thought there are some fixes for quit() keyword in version 0.9.6RC3, so I'll not use the quit() keyword now onward. Also will go through the instructions. Thanks Shekhar

Comment: hi I have observed that for one data set it is working fine. However for more than one data set it is not working properly. For second data set Karate is executing test in same browser session due to which test are getting fail, as it fails to identify elements properly due to same browser session might be. It would be helpful if could provide your inputs. Thanks

Comment: @ShekharPatil I will only provide my inputs if you follow the process in the link in my answer

Comment: raised issue https://github.com/intuit/karate/issues/1180 Thanks

Comment: @ShekharPatil and replied. you did not follow the instructions and karate is working fine